# How can I play the system shutter sound?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In Swift I would call this method:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1108)
```

Supposedly I can play system sounds with the SystemSound class, but I don't see a way of specifying an ID. How can I do this in Xamarin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to import the sound on your own, as the [SysSound class](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/sound/syssound-example/) uses a local sound in the project rather than the sounds that come with iOS. You can follow this guide [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/SysSound/).

I couldn't find anything in the App Store Guidelines pertaining to using Apple's sounds indirectly (via importing them into your project), but I'm guessing it's not allowed and would result in a rejection. So you may be best off finding a similar camera shutter sound elsewhere and then use that with the [SysSound class](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/sound/syssound-example/)

Comment: What's so sad is that I'm supposedly calling Apple's APIs in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

Manually call the method using P/Invoke, like this:

```
[DllImport (Constants.AudioToolboxLibrary)]
static extern void AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(uint inSystemSoundID);
```

And pass the ID;   That said, Apple does not document those numbers, so it is possible that the sound might change across versions, depending on the order they are registered.   You might want to use instead:

```
var sound = SystemSound.FromFile ("/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/photoShutter.caf");
sound.PlaySystemSound ()
```